# I can't get into my field research prize

Tags: pokemon-go, technical-issues

I finished all my field research tasks last night and attempted to capture Raikou, but ran out of Pokeballs. I fled the capture, assuming I could come back later and do it again once I had collected more.

Today the prize is still there, but every time I click it takes me to a blue and white screen and nothing happens. I have rebooted and signed out to try and restart it but now I don't know what to do. Any ideas? Has anyone experienced this?

[image: field research]
[image: blank screen]

Comment: I experience the same after having claimed my 7 day field research reward (currently Raikou) for two days already. I've made a video of the bug: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2U2A2zP3bcE
Note that the screen doesn't just become white but you're actually stuck on the map. You can click nearby ground, zoom in and out and are able to see the sky when fully zoomed in. Furthermore it's possible to exit the game using the back button while in this state.
Feel free to update your question with this information for completeness.

Answer (score 12):

## Update your game

As of 19th August 2018, Niantic has released an update which appears to include a patch that addresses this bug. The Android version is v0.115.3, I'm not sure of the iOS version number.

It's not a forced upgrade, so you may have to go into the Play Store/App Store on your device, and update the game manually.

---

### What caused this?

Niantic [released a statement](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001855747)  regarding this bug:

> We are aware of an issue on Android version 0.111.4 and iOS version 1.81.4 that causes Pokémon GO to become unresponsive when encountering a Pokémon that you have previously fed a Berry to. We are currently working on a fix but in the meantime, you will need to restart the app to continue playing.

It seems that feeding a berry to a Pokemon, fleeing from the capture screen, then re-entering the capture caused this issue.

---

### What about my lost research task?

If your research task Pokemon capture was somehow lost in the process, then you may be able to recover it. According to user Borinkito who experienced similar issues:

> If you have been impacted by this update, you may be able to recover your research task rewards. Please send your email address and Trainer nickname through this form and include the phrase #ResearchReward: [Niantic Support Form](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=319988&form_type=bugs)
> <sub>[Borinkito](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/337482/unable-to-claim-reward-after-completing-field-research-how-can-i-fix-this#comment477762_337482) - Unable to claim reward after completing field research, how can I fix this?</sub>

Comment: Despite the statement of niantic being still "in the works", as of today (19th of August 2018), the new update released has solved this issue for me. Claiming my stacked field reward now revealed that I had indeed given a Misdreavus a Pinap Berry which seems to have bugged the encounter.
You might want to edit your answer

Comment: @Vinzenz thanks for the heads up! You wouldn't happen to know the iOS version number?

Comment: Sadly friends have reported that they have no update on their IOS devices as of yet. Looks like this is only fixed on android devices currently.