# Unable to claim reward after completing field research, how can I fix this?

Tags: pokemon-go

Pokémon Go graphic glitch.  My daughter was trying to capture Raikou, after feeding berries and several failed attempts with ultra balls she fled the capture prize screen.  When trying to go back and capture the prize we are brought to a blurry bluish white screen with no buttons or options to click on.  Please help!!!

Here’s a video of my issue:

!

[Blurry screen when trythe no to capture Raickou](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCWCX.jpg)

Comment: @Borinkito - It's ok, we mark questions as duplicate so that in future, people can get the answers they're looking for from one place :). I think Raikou will stay there, I can't guarantee it, but so long as it still shows 'Claim Reward' on the field research screen, it *should* be ok until Niantic can release a patch... whenever that may be...

Comment: Just got this from one of my discord chats! 
NianticHelp: If you have been impacted by this update, you may be able to recover your research task rewards. Please send your email address and Trainer nickname through this form and include the phrase #ResearchReward https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=319988&form_type=bugs

Comment: I hope this helps everyone with this issue.

Comment: Thanks @Borinkito! hopefully that will help a lot of people :) I've added that info into my answer on the other question to help signal-boost it a bit, attributing you, I hope that's alright :)